# How to increase size of bounding box using find contour open cv?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

I have prepared bounding box for text region using MSER methods.i can increase box size  only for one bounding box.  problem is i would like to increase the size of all predicted  bounding boxes using Find contour method. here with i will enclose my code .

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

mser = cv2.MSER_create()
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Mani/Desktop/img/87.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
vis = img.copy()

coordinates, bboxes = mser.detectRegions(gray)


for bbox in bboxes:
    x, y, w, h = bbox
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cx = x + w//2
cy = y + h//2
cr = max(w,h)//2

dr = 10
idx=0
for i in bbox:
    idx+=1
    r = cr + i*dr
    cv2.rectangle(vis,(cx-r,cy-r),(cx+r,cy+r),(0,255,0),2)
    croped =img[cy-r:cy+r,cx-r:cx+r]
    cv2.imshow("croped{}".format(i), croped)
```

Answer (score 0):

You always picking the last of the `bboxes`. To process them all you can add the cropping code to the first for-loop:

```
dr = 10
idx=0

for bbox in bboxes:
    x, y, w, h = bbox
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cx = x + w//2
    cy = y + h//2
    cr = max(w,h)//2

    idx+=1
    r = cr + i*dr
    cv2.rectangle(vis,(cx-r,cy-r),(cx+r,cy+r),(0,255,0),2)
    croped =img[cy-r:cy+r,cx-r:cx+r]
    cv2.imshow("croped{}".format(i), croped)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I have tried with what u suggest but i get error like "   cv2.rectangle(img,(cx-r,cy-r),(cx+r,cy+r),(0,255,0),1)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)"

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would guess `img` is grayscale, so you have to input a single color integer like  cv2.rectangle(img,(cx-r,cy-r),(cx+r,cy+r),127,1). `print` the input values to be sure